# How do I remove onedrive for business files and folders from appearing in a sharepoint online search?

Tags: search, search-results, sharepoint-search, onedrive-for-business, settings

For some reason the people who previously set up a sharepoint online and the search page I now manage decided to include onedrive files and folders in the search page results. I know how to stop the search results from appearing for each site/onedrive by changing the Search and Offline Availability settings and changing the site settings in Documents > Settings > Advance > Settings however I don't want to do that for all of them, it's too time consuming.

Is there a search setting that I can change to stop onedrive files and folders from appearing in a sharepoint online search?

Standard Office365 setup with sharepoint online and onedrive for business

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is worth mentioning that anybody who performs a search will be shown in results only the onedrive files that he has in HIS/HER onedrive or the ones that other people shared with him/her.

So it is not like anybody can search in everybody else's onedrive. Just the data they have access to.

BTW this has been always the standard default behavior since forever, even when onedrive was branded 'mysite'

Comment: I think it was different to the above; for example a user searches for the word contract in the sharepoint search bar. The results the user gets shows files containing the word contract in sharepoint and onedrive. Some of the onedrive results the user has no access to as no one has shared it with them. The user can click on them but they will not open. By doing what I did in my initial post these results then vanish from the results.

Comment: It can be that the file has been unshared, it might take some minutes to be removed from indexing. OneDrive is not 'public' by any means. By deactivating the indexing there you would do a great disservice since at that point it would be impossible even for the owner of that onedrive to search in HIS onedrive. Check also if the file 'contract' has not been shared by mistake with 'everybody'. The sharing interface in onedrive is not particularly easy to digest.

Comment: I understand that the user will not be able to search the users own onedrive if indexing for their onedrive is turned off however isn't there a setting or settings that can be changed on the search side to omit onedrive results?

Comment: Also thank you for replying :)